Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.barpolar.Marker: 'pattern'
I was trying to make a graph using Plotly but I kept getting this error. Below is my current code and was confused on why it said invalid property specified for Marker: pattern since I do not instantiate any pattern or a marker.
`def visualize_plan(cleaned_vals):
    traces = []
    for i, tech in enumerate(techs):
        traces.append(go.Bar(
            x=dateTime,
            y=cleaned_vals[i],
            name=f'Tech {tech}',
 
        ))
    # Create the layout for the figure
    layout = go.Layout(
        title='Stacked Bar Graph of Technologies Over Time',
        xaxis=dict(title='Date'),
        yaxis=dict(title='Values'),
        barmode='stack'
    )
    # Create the figure and add traces
    fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
    # Export the figure to JSON
    fig_json = fig.to_json()
    # Save the JSON to a file
    with open('figure.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(fig_json)`

Variable Formats
`cleaned_vals = [[-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 5.0, 15.0],
 [-0.0, -0.0, 10.0, 15.0, 15.0],
 [5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0],
 [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 5.0],
 [15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0]]

dateTime = DatetimeIndex(['2025-12-31', '2026-12-31', '2027-12-31', '2028-12-31',
               '2029-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

techs = Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')`

I am running this function from a notebook in the same folder but I think the issue is not related to this.
I have tried updating my plotly by running pip3 install --upgrade plotly which did successfully update the version but still did not fix the issue.

It appears that the error is not caused by your code. I was able to run it in my jupyterlab (latest version) and Plotly (latest version). I also ran it in Colab with the latest version of plotly and it ran correctly. Is it due to other environmental aspects?

Hi, just figured it out and was able to get it to work. I just exported the graph into an HTML format instead of a Json format which managed to work. Kinda weird on why it is bugging out on the json part however.
